# gradle build gives Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'

Tags: gradle

Gradle version 7.6.4
Java openjdk@17

```
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.10/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gradle@7/7.6.4/libexec/lib/gradle-launcher-7.6.4.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 7.6.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 17 has removed MaxPermSize option.
To resolve,

1. Installed JDK11
2. Added a file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
3. Added the below line in it.

   org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home

On mac, list the path for java homes available by running

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```